# ¿Cómo crear el promedio(AVG) de Inputs generados?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, tengo la siguiente tabla en `notas.php`

[image: notas]

Lo que hace es generar un RUT(ID de la persona), el nombre, el apellido y las notas de esa persona. Y me gustaría añadir la columna de Promedio, es decir un Avg de todas las notas que tiene ese estudiante y dejarlo como última columna.

Este es el código de  `notas.php`

```
<table class="table table-hover" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
      <td colspan="3" border="1"><center>Información de los alumnos</center></td>
       <td colspan="2" border="5"><center>Notas de los alumnos</center></td>
   </tr>
<tr>
<td><b>RUT</b></td>
<td><b>Nombre</b></td>
<td><b>Apellido</b></td>
<td><b>Notas</b></td>
<td><b>Promedio</b></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","liceo");
if (!$connect) {
die(mysqli_error());
}
$results = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM alumnos, curso_alumnos WHERE alumnos.rut=curso_alumnos.rut AND curso_alumnos.curso='$ola'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($results)) {
$rut = $row->rut;
$boo = 0; /* Iniciamos la Variable Auxiliar
          que indicará cuantas notas se imprimió  por cada Alumno  */
          $q=$_POST['cont'];
$results2 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT nota FROM notas WHERE rut_alumno = '$rut' AND id_materia=".$q." LIMIT 5");

?>
<tr>
<td><?=$row->rut?></td>
<td><?=$row->nombre?></td>
<td><?=$row->apellido?></td>
<td>
<?php
while($nota = mysqli_fetch_object($results2)): {
$color = ($nota->nota >= 40)? '#0000ff' : '#ff0000'
?>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $row->rut  ?>" maxlength="2" size="2" value="<?php echo $nota->nota ?>" style="color: <?php echo $color; ?>">
<?php } ?>

<?php
    $boo +=1;/* Incrementamos después de Imprimir la nota del Alumno*/
endwhile;
/* Si la variable es menor a 5 , es decir no se imprimieron las 5 notas respectivas*/
if($boo<5){ 
    /* Imprimimos  inputs de value 0 hasta que sea < 5 , dado que si el
    el valor de $boo es 1 o 0 , primero se realizará el echo y luego el incremento
    Sí $boo es 0 -> Iteración 0 - Imprime el input - Incrementa $boo -> $boo = 1
                    Iteración 1 - Imprime el input - Incrementa $boo -> $boo = 2
                    Termina el for dado que 2 no es menor que 2
    Sí $boo es 1 -> Iteración 0 - Imprime el input - Incrementa $boo -> $boo = 2
                    Termina el For dado que 2 no es menor que 2
     */
    for (; $boo < 5; $boo++) { 
        echo '<input type="text" name="' . $row->rut . '" maxlength="2" size="2" value="" onchange="cambio(this)">    ';
    }
}
?>
</td>

</tr>
<?php
  }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Y esta es mi tabla `notas` dentro de la base de datos

[image: tabladb]

Y me gustaría añadir la columna de Promedio, es decir un AVG de todas las notas que tiene ese estudiante y dejarlo como última columna.
Agradezco si pueden guiarme

Comment: Gracias por la sentencia @Dev.Joel, pero lo que no logro es implementarlo y dejarlo como última columna

Comment: Sí añade la recomendación del `AVG` a la consulta `SELECT nota , AVG(nota) avg FROM notas...` , después de cerrar el `if($boo<5)` , puede imprimir algo así `echo '<input type="text" name="' . $row->avg . '>';`  a ver que resultado obtiene

Comment: Agradezco tu guía, lo implementé pero me da un notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$avg in line 460.

Comment: @dev-joel esta en lo cierto, pero se equivoco en el BUCLE,

Pon eso mismo pero `$nota->avg`

Comment: Aun así no te va a funcionar bien, tienes un problema conceptual ( y no se si también de relación con la BB.DD si nos pasas la estructura de tablas lo miramos)

Deberías sacar todo en una misma consulta de SQL

Answer (score 0):

Las consultas anidadas deberían ser evitadas siempre que sea posible y en tu caso seguramente lo es.  No obstante desconocemos la estructura de tus tablas por lo que es difícil darte una solución certera.

Igualmente te dejo una posible solución calculando la media en php.

Es solo un ejemplo pero creo que se entenderá la idea:

```
$media=0;
$boo=0;
while( $nota = mysqli_fetch_object($results2) )
{
    $media += $nota->nota;
    $boo++;
    /* Resto de acciones */
}

$media = $media / $boo; 
echo 'Media = ' . $media;
unset ( $media );
```

Obviamente esta puede no ser la solución más óptima, pero dado el código que presentas puede ser la más simple.